# nested ng-repeat in angular js not showing anything

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am having this inside my controller method.

```
var employee = [{name:"ankur",dept:"IT",company:"wipro",under:[{name1:"ashish"},{name1:"akash"},{name1:"tyagi"},{name1:"mogra"}]}];
    $scope.employee = employee;
```

and this inside html page.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in employee">
        <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.dept}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.company}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(key , value) in emp.under">
            a<td>{{key}}</td>
            b<td>{{value}}</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, first ng-repeat is working fine, but it shows nothing at place of nested ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-repeat is fine, The problem is with the `td inside another td`, to do that you can do like this instead :

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/suzo/9z9h1esk/)

```
 <div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
   <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in employee">
        <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.dept}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.company}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(key , value) in emp.under">{{value.name1}}
           <table>
             <tr>
              a<td>{{key}}</td>
              b<td>{{value.name1}}</td>
             </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

If you just want to check if your ng-repeat is working, remove the `<td>`'s and check like this :

```
 <td ng-repeat="(key , value) in emp.under">
        a{{key}}
        b{{value}}
 </td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and its working fine now, but it wonder why i did not work in td element. Does position of elements also play role in evaluating ng expressions ?

Comment: No. problem is not with the ng-repeat, `td` cannot be inside another `td`, hence it is not getting rendered . That's the reason it worked when you remove it.

Comment: Anyway, glad I could help. Happy coding :)